# Different combinations of groups

Tags: r

I am searching for a function in R where I could create different groups with a binary variable. 
My data looks like

```
data <- data.frame(Var1 = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",2),rep("C",3)))
data
```

and the result table should look like this:

```
result <- data.frame(Var1 = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",2),rep("C",3)),
                     Group1 = rep(1,10),
                     Group2 = c(rep(0,5),rep(1,5)),
                     Group3 = c(rep(1,5),rep(0,2),rep(1,3)),
                     Group4 = c(rep(1,7),rep(0,3)))
result
```

For every possible group one column where the creating-group-reference is the first column (`Var1`)

Thank you for your help!

I have again one thing: Now we only exclude one group. How could we create groups where really all possible combinations (e.g. 2 excluded, 3 excluded...) are considered?

```r
result <- data.frame(Var1 = c(letters[1:5]),
                     Group1 = rep(1,5),
                     Group2 = c(0,rep(1,4)),
                     Group3 = c(1,0,rep(1,3)),
                     Group4 = c(rep(1,2),0,rep(1,2)),
                     Group5 = c(rep(1,3),0,1),
                     Group6 = c(rep(1,4),0),
                     Group7 = c(rep(0,2),rep(1,3)),
                     Group8 = c(rep(0,3),rep(1,2)))
result
```

That's not all possible combinations, it's just an example how it could go on...

Comment: How are the `Group1` ... `Group4` values defined? In your example it looks like for all `A` items `Group2` is zero while the other groups are one, whereas for `B` items `Group3` is zero and for `C` items `Group4`. Is that correct?

Comment: no matter if `A` item is `Group2` or `C`item is `Group4`. `A`item could also be `Group3`. The item is not linked to a specific `GroupX`

Comment: I don't get it. So the `GroupX` columns are independent of `Var1`? Then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Is `Group1` always `1`?

Comment: I just want to have a results data frame where one column represents one group. The first column should include every variable (`A`,`B` and `C`). The second column should include all variables **without** `A`. The third column should include all variables **wihtout** `B` and so on. And there are finally just two groups (binary variable `0`and `1`) I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which basically creates all combinations of your `Var1` and mathces them with the original `Var1`, i.e.

```
#Get unique Var1
i1 <- unique(as.character(data$Var1))
#Get all combinations
l1 <- sapply(2:length(i1), function(i) combn(i1, i, FUN = toString))
#match to see which Var1 is in each group
df2 <- sapply(unlist(l1), function(i)sapply(i1, function(j)grepl(j, i)*1))
#Merge
merge(data, df2, by.x = 'Var1', by.y = 'row.names')
```

which gives,

> ```
>    Var1 A, B A, C B, C A, B, C
> 1     A    1    1    0       1
> 2     A    1    1    0       1
> 3     A    1    1    0       1
> 4     A    1    1    0       1
> 5     A    1    1    0       1
> 6     B    1    0    1       1
> 7     B    1    0    1       1
> 8     C    0    1    1       1
> 9     C    0    1    1       1
> 10    C    0    1    1       1
> ```

Comment: You are right! I didn't consider every possible group indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `base R`, where `ifelse` is used:

```
df <- cbind(data,
            Group1 = 1,
            `colnames<-`(sapply(levels(data$Var1), 
                                function(v) ifelse(data$Var1==v,1,0)),paste0("Group",1+seq(levels(data$Var1)))))
```

such that

```
> df
   Var1 Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5
1     A      1      1      0      0      0
2     A      1      1      0      0      0
3     A      1      1      0      0      0
4     A      1      1      0      0      0
5     A      1      1      0      0      0
6     B      1      0      1      0      0
7     B      1      0      1      0      0
8     C      1      0      0      1      0
9     C      1      0      0      1      0
10    C      1      0      0      1      0
11    D      1      0      0      0      1
12    D      1      0      0      0      1
```

**DATA**

```
data <- data.frame(Var1 = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",2),rep("C",3),rep("D",2)))

> data
   Var1
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     A
5     A
6     B
7     B
8     C
9     C
10    C
11    D
12    D
```